# How to install WebGL in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, webgl

I'm a newbie in webGL development and in order to learn it i'll have to install webGL in my machine. Can anyone tell how to do that in Windows 7? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [these instructions](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=11).

Comment: That link is broken.